# Concatenate two EagerTensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have two EagerTensor of type :

```
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
```

tensor1 of size(64, 100) and tensor2 of size(64, 10).
I want output to be in the dimension (64, 110).
I tried:

```
tf.concat(axis=1, values = [tensor1, tensor2])
```

Getting an error :

```
InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute ConcatV2 as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a uint8 tensor but is a float tensor [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat
```

But not working, Please help.

Comment: Got it thanks @GPhilo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that both tensors have the same type when concatenating. Cast the uint8 one to float (more likely what you want), or vice-versa (though casting float to uint8 will likely not give you the results you expect)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

tensor1 = tf.ones([64, 10], dtype=tf.uint8)
tensor2 = tf.ones([64, 100], dtype=tf.float32)
# print(type(x))            # <type 'EagerTensor'>

tf.concat(axis=1, values = [tf.cast(tensor1, tf.float32), tensor2]) # <<<< note the cast
```